# Are there consequences to carrying an old passport together with a new passport?

Tags: passports, security, passport-stamps

I just renewed my passport. I was thinking to carry my old passport the collect this stamps like in this [other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26341/are-there-consequences-to-stamps-in-my-passport-that-are-not-from-border-control) and following the recommendations of have just official stamps in my passport.

In a security control will I have problems carrying two passports of the same nationality and name but one with the expired date?

Comment: You _should_ do this if your old passport has a valid visa in it that you wish to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this will not be a problem. You are permitted to do this. Often times, I have had a valid visa on my old passport but I am using my current passport for travel.